# Unable to send image to other apps via Intent

Tags: android

I have saved image on the sdcard and then I am trying to send the image via Intent to other applications. however when I try the below code, other apps are not receiving image and also they appear to be crashing. Here str1 is the path to that image on the sdcard. What am I doing wrong here? Need help
Thanks

```
 String str1 = file1.getAbsolutePath();
           Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
           shareIntent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
           shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(str1));
           shareIntent.setType("image/jpg");

           startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.share_image)));
```

Comment: What is in your logcat?

Comment: android.content.contentresolver.openInputStream, Fatal Exception:SyncAdapterThread

Comment: What happens if you contruct your Uri this way instead: Uri.fromFile(file1) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By specifying the image as jpeg, it helped in sharing via intent.

shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");